# WebGL solid colors

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, glsl, webgl

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zkhtdv4yaqhpxy/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-28%2010%3A42%3A02%201.png?dl=0
Can someone explain to me, what am I doing wrong? I want every face of the cube to have one solid colour. The code, which creates the cube, is in RunCube.coffee file and the vertices and colour are defined in Cube.coffee file. I think the problem is that I do not know, how to use indexes for colours.
Here is the repository on github https://github.com/trimpirim/shiny-soice

UPDATED:
I have Cube with all it's data.

```
@vertices: [
  [ 6.89954888016507530,  0.39691390817415106, -4.02972512706645780],
  [-0.78006682662096161, -3.78853119791598660, -7.00275139558893490],
  [-5.79336942493284560,  3.47790796230961650, -4.28264251507835430],
  [ 1.88624628185319150,  7.66335306839975420, -1.30961624655587690],
  [ 0.78006682662096205,  3.78853119791598920,  7.00275139558893490],
  [ 5.79336942493284290, -3.47790796230961740,  4.28264251507835780],
  [-1.88624628185319150, -7.66335306839975150,  1.30961624655588270],
  [-6.89954888016507440, -0.39691390817415328,  4.02972512706646220]
];

@faces: [
  [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3],
  [0, 3, 4], [0, 4, 5],
  [0, 5, 6], [0, 6, 1]
  [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 7],
  [2, 7, 4], [2, 4, 3],
  [4, 7, 6], [4, 6, 5]
];

@colors: [
  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
  [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
  [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
]
```

Can someone tell me, how should correct colours data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There **are not** separated indices for colors. Indices are same for both, vertex positions and colors (or any other property you could think of).

To achive cube with 6 solid colors, you will have to repeat some parts of your arrays.

This is kind of prototype, how vertices look like:

```
vertices: [
    {
        position: [x,y,z],
        color: [r, g, b, a]
    },
    {
        position: [x,y,z],
        color: [r, g, b, a]
    },
    ...
];
```

Vertex with `position: [0,0,0], color [1,0,0,1]` is not same as vertex with `position: [0,0,0], color [0,1,0,1]`. You want one corner of cube be part of 3 faces with different color. So there must be 3 vertices in one corner with same position, but different color. Unfortunately in this case, position cannot be shared.

So your definition should look like this:

```
var vertex_positions = [
    // see that front face and back face has 8 unique positions
    // front face
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    // back face
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    // see that bottom face and top face has 8 unique positions too,
    // but they repeated with different order from front and back
    // bottom face
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1],
    // top face
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    // left and right face have 8 unique positions too, but again
    // repeated from front, back / bottom, top
    // left face
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1],
    // right face
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1]
];
```

Colors, same amount of elements as for positions:

```
var vertex_colors = [
    // front face
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    // back face
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    // bottom face
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    // top face
    [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
    // left face
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    // right face
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
];
```

Now indices:

```
var triangles = [
    // front face
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 3],
    // back face
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 6, 7],
    // bottom face
    [8, 9, 10],
    [8, 10, 11],
    // top face
    [12, 13, 14],
    [12, 14, 15],
    // left face
    [16, 17, 18],
    [16, 18, 19],
    // right face
    [20, 21, 22],
    [20, 22, 23]
];
```

Cube is made of 12 triangles. With solid color faces, we need 4 unique vertices for 2 triangles, so we need 24 different vertex definitions.

This is the most traditional way as gman said. There are also other ways to achieve same effect, but theirs usecases are rare.

PS: sorry my indices might not be correct

Comment: This is true the way most people use WebGL shaders but it's not technically true. You can write shaders that use different indices for each of position, texcoord, etc...  For example [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7t2Dj/) puts the vertex data into textures and then uses different indices for normals and positions. Note: I don't recommend this method but it's important to at least understand that WebGL/GLSL does what you tell it. You can use it in creative ways.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand:/. Take a look at the updated question, I hope you could explain me better. Thanks